# How to get rid of this ffmpeg?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, discord.js

I am currently working on a bot. Its function is to join voice channels and speak with `tts`.

This is my attempt so far :

```
try {
    const broadcast = client.voice.createBroadcast();
    var channelId = message.member.voice.channelID;
    var channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
    channel.join().then(connection => {
        broadcast.play(discordTTS.getVoiceStream("Staline est né le : 18 Décembre 1878."));
        const dispatcher = connection.play(broadcast);
    });
    message.delete();
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
events.js: 292
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: spawn ffmpeg ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(internal / child_process.js: 269: 19)
at onErrorNT(internal / child_process.js: 465: 16)
at processTicksAndRejections(internal / process / task_queues.js: 80: 21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(internal / child_process.js: 275: 12)
at onErrorNT(internal / child_process.js: 465: 16)
at processTicksAndRejections(internal / process / task_queues.js: 80: 21) {
    errno: -4058,
        code: 'ENOENT',
            syscall: 'spawn ffmpeg',
                path: 'ffmpeg',
                    spawnargs: [
                        '-i', '-',
                        '-analyzeduration', '0',
                        '-loglevel', '0',
                        '-f', 's16le',
                        '-ar', '48000',
                        '-ac', '2',
                        'pipe:1'
                    ]
}
```

I really don't understand, I never asked for ffmpeg to be here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know /tts is inner Discord's function (not discord.js). Bot can't join and speak by tts.
You can make something like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    message.channel.send(args, {
        tts: true
    });
});
```

**Without joining voice channel!**

Update!

I didn't mention that you are using "discord-tts".
First of all you have to install all needed dependencies:
**@discordjs/opus** and **ffmpeg-static**

Then try your code or this:

```
if (msg.content==="say test 123") {
    const broadcast = bot.voice.createBroadcast();

    if (msg.member.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await msg.member.voice.channel.join();

        broadcast.play(discordTTS.getVoiceStream("test 123"));

        const dispatcher = connection.play(broadcast);

    } else {
        await msg.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I was installing ffmpeg everytime and not ffmpeg-static, thank you :D